# “No locks available” when run sbt cmd

Tags: java, sbt

to building spark project, I tried to use sbt.  The following exception is occured:

```
java.io.IOException: No locks available
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:871)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:962)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:88)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:279)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:157)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:157)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:142)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:178)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:91)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: No locks available
```

the sbt version i have tried: 0.11.3-2 and 0.13.0
I aslo tried changing the sbt boot dir to avoid permission issues.

Any idea that I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

SBT relies on your jvm's property "user.home" as working directory, and **SEEMS** acquire locks in there, if your "user.home" point to a NFS directory which didn't install NFS lock service, then you'll get the "No locks available" error.

I've encountered this error several times(another case is maven trying acquire some locks under $HOME/.m2/...). You have two options:

- Install NFS lock service
- Tell sbt don't use your directory in NFS, by passing property -Duser.home=/path/in/local/disk. eg.

  - `sbt clean compile -Duser.home=/disk1/myhome`

Comment: Yes,w e try to acquire a lock in ~/.ivy2/ to make sure only one process is touching the ivy cache, to avoid corruption issues we experiecned.

You can disable this.

Comment: Thanks for informing this. I think acquiring lock to avoid corruption is needed for me, and maven will acquire a lock in $HOME anyway, so I just use a local $HOME. Unfortunally my company's cluster dont have a NFS lock...

Answer (score 2):

By default sbt tried to aquire an exclusive lock when booting or doing dependency resolution.  This is to avoid cache corruption, or the deletion of JAR files that another process is using (which can cause some very strange errors).

This locking is not compatible with distributed file systems, usually.  Sometimes it even fails on local filesystems with unexpected implementations.  Check your FS to see if Java supports locking on it.

You should be able to disable this locking via:

```
sbt -Dsbt.boot.lock=false
```

Addtionally, if you have your own `sbt.boot.properties` file, you need the following:

```
[boot]
lock: false
```

This will disable the locking feature inside the launcher, which in-turn disables locking for all of sbt projects which use this feature.   AFAIK this means everything in sbt, although some plugins may be directly using the JDK locking APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what's wrong, but I suspect your issue may be similar to [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/iYvBRIRVcGA). Are you building with your project and/or your copy of sbt and/or your home directory on an NFS mount? Have you tried doing the build entirely from a local disk?